# Least CPU load with Timer/ScheduledThreadPool for changing element very often

Tags: java, android, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to program a little Android App and I want to update an element on my activity
after a button is pressed very quickly and often (every ~50-250 ms).

I also want to be able to update the speed how often the element is changed while
the timer is running.

And so I always use "Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()" to create a new 
single thread.
But is this the best solution concerning CPU/RAM?

I really need to change this element very often and I don't want the device to lag.

Current Code:

```
// OnCreate
    mtimerTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // set some variables
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update some things on the Activity
            }
        });
    }
    };
    mscheduledPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    // onclickListener
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mscheduledPool.isShutdown() || firstExecute) { 
        // firstExecute necessary because isShutdown is always false at the beginning
                    firstExecute = false;
        mscheduledPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(mtimerTask, 0, sleepTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // sleepTime standard = 200
                } else {
                    mscheduledPool.shutdownNow();
                }
            }
        });


// triggered by buttons
private void updateSpeed(boolean increase) {
    if (increase) {
        someValue += 25;
        sleepTime = Math.round((60 * 1000) / someValue);
        if (!mscheduledPool.isShutdown()) {
            mscheduledPool.shutdownNow();
            mscheduledPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            mscheduledPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(mtimerTask, 0, sleepTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
    else {
        someValue -= 25;
        sleepTime = Math.round((60 * 1000) / someValue);
        if (!mscheduledPool.isShutdown()) {
            mscheduledPool.shutdownNow();
            mscheduledPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            mscheduledPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(mtimerTask, 0, sleepTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe using the "ScheduleFuture" returned by "mscheduledPool.scheduleAtFixedRate" is more resourcesparing?

Looking forward to your answers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your idea is to only update the UI of the activity and not perform heavy computations, network access, db access, etc. I recommend you use the `Handler.postDelayed()` method. It will enqueue a runnable on the main thread and in said runnable you can perform your UI modifications.

That way you won't have to create a new thread and manage it on your own.

As for every question regarding memory usage and performance, it will actually make sense to implement both solutions and profile the app. This way you will have a clear indication of the resources used by both approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the Handler.postDelayed runs a Runnable only once and I want it to run every X seconds and I also want to be able to change the time between 2 executions (like I do in my code with newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor)

Comment: You can achieve this by calling `postDelayed()` again from your runnable. That way you will have the recurring execution and you will be able to adjust the interval between the updates.

Comment: oh right didn't think about that. I will definitly try that tomorrow thanks :D